# salesforce Migration Issue between one org to another org

Tags: ant, salesforce

I am trying to automate migration process of Salesforce form one org(developer) to an another org(developer) which is completely fresh. I am automating this process with the help of Jenkins and ANT migration Tools. When I had few set of custom objects and custom fields it worked flawless but now I am trying to apply it on production which has huge set of custom objects, custom fields, layouts,triggers,etc. Now I am facing issues like Invalid Field, No custom field, No such column on entity,Apex Class does not exist,etc.

I could understand one thing here the objects are not exist in the target org, why objects are not taken care by ANT migration tool.

Why it says Apex class does n't exist, I guess it nothing to do with the Objects?

What I am missing here, I hope anyone of you might have came across this kind of issues.

I have used retrieveUnpackaged tag to retrieve components from source org and have used deployUnpackaged tag to deploy on the target.

Package.xml(From retrieved contents)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomPageWebLink</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageLayout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

Errors

```
[sf:deploy] Component Failures:
[sf:deploy] 2.  objects/Service_Request__c.object (Service_Request__c.Entitlement__c) -- Error: referenceTo value of 'Entitlement' does not resolve to a valid sObject type (line 315, column 13)
[sf:deploy] 3.  objects/Quote__c.object (Quote__c.Service_Contract__c) -- Error: referenceTo value of 'ServiceContract' does not resolve to a valid sObject type (line 198, column 13)
[sf:deploy] 4.  objects/Product_Complaint__c.object (Product_Complaint__c.Asset__c) -- Error: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown> (line 392, column 13)
[sf:deploy] 5.  objects/Order__c.object (Order__c.Entitlement__c) -- Error: referenceTo value of 'Entitlement' does not resolve to a valid sObject type (line 108, column 13)
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Component Failures:
[sf:deploy] 6.  objects/Service_Request__c.object (Service_Request__c.Service_Contract__c) -- Error: referenceTo value of 'ServiceContract' does not resolve to a valid sObject type (line 499, column 13)
[sf:deploy] 7.  objects/Discount_Matrix__c.object (Discount_Matrix__c.AccountRecordType_not_eq_be_Account_Type) -- Error: Field RecordType does not exist. Check spelling. (line 334, column 22)
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Component Failures:
[sf:deploy] 8.  objects/Order__c.object (Order__c.All) -- Error: In field: columns - no CustomField named Order__c.Entitlement__c found (line 207, column 16)
[sf:deploy] 9.  objects/Service_Request__c.object (Service_Request__c.Edit_View_Field_Set) -- Error: In field: Entitlement__c - no CustomField named Service_Request__c.Entitlement__c found (line 107, column 26)
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (1777/2200)  -- Processing Type: Layout
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Component Failures:
[sf:deploy] 10.  objects/Discount_Matrix__c.object (Discount_Matrix__c.Distributor_Account__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Account.RecordType.Name (line 182, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 11.  objects/Inventory_Transactions__c.object (Inventory_Transactions__c.Destination_Customer__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Account.RecordType.DeveloperName (line 64, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 12.  objects/Inventory_Transactions__c.object (Inventory_Transactions__c.Source_Customer__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Account.RecordType.DeveloperName (line 150, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 13.  objects/RMA__c.object (RMA__c.Warranty_Card_No_Invoice_No__c) -- Error: Field Warranty_Card_No_Invoice_No__c does not exist. Check spelling. (line 985, column 13)
[sf:deploy] 14.  objects/Sales_Order__c.object (Sales_Order__c.Bill_To_Account__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Account.RecordTypeId (line 171, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 15.  objects/Sales_Order__c.object (Sales_Order__c.Ship_To_Account__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Account.RecordTypeId (line 357, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 16.  objects/Sales_Order__c.object (Sales_Order__c.Sold_To_Account__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Account.RecordTypeId (line 378, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 17.  objects/Work_Order__c.object (Work_Order__c.Installed_Location__c) -- Error: Field Asset__r does not exist. Check spelling. (line 1133, column 13)
[sf:deploy] 18.  layouts/Account-Affiliates Account.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Preferred_Shipping_Method__c found (line 31, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 19.  layouts/Account-Billing Account Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Payment_Terms__c found (line 25, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 20.  layouts/Account-Clinic Account.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Institute_Speciality__c found (line 25, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 21.  layouts/Account-Export partner Account.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Preferred_Shipping_Method__c found (line 29, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 22.  layouts/Account-Fulfillment Shipper Account.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Global_Presence__c found (line 24, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 23.  layouts/Account-GPO.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Email_Address__c found (line 53, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 24.  layouts/Account-Health Authority.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.RecordTypeId found (line 25, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 25.  layouts/Account-Hospital Account.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Institute_Speciality__c found (line 24, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 26.  layouts/Account-IDN.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.RecordTypeId found (line 36, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 27.  layouts/Account-Laboratories Account.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Laboratory_Speciality_1__c found (line 37, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 28.  layouts/Account-Pharmacy Account.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Preferred_Shipping_Method__c found (line 28, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 29.  layouts/Account-Purchase Account.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Email_Address__c found (line 29, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 30.  layouts/Account-Shipping Account.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Email_Address__c found (line 25, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 31.  layouts/Account-Supplier Account.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Account.Payment_Terms__c found (line 28, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 32.  layouts/Asset__c-Asset Layout.layout -- Error: In field: relatedList - no CustomField named Case.Asset__c found (line 176, column 19)
[sf:deploy] 33.  layouts/Case-Case %28Marketing%29 Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Date_of_Purchase__c found (line 42, column 26)
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Component Failures:
[sf:deploy] 34.  layouts/Case-Case %28Sales%29 Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Date_of_Purchase__c found (line 34, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 35.  layouts/User-User Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named User.Adt_Short_Name__c found (line 9, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 36.  layouts/Case-Case Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Asset__c found (line 37, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 37.  layouts/Case-Case Master Layout Customer Portal.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Asset__c found (line 20, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 38.  layouts/Case-Case Master layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 37, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 39.  layouts/Case-Case Order Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 41, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 40.  layouts/Case-Case Product Complaint Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 41, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 41.  layouts/Case-Case RFI Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 41, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 42.  layouts/Case-Case ROR Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 41, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 43.  layouts/Case-Case Service Request Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 41, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 44.  layouts/CaseClose-Close Case Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.User_To_Be_Surveyed__c found (line 21, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 45.  layouts/CaseClose-Close Case Layout %28Product Complaint%29.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.User_To_Be_Surveyed__c found (line 21, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 46.  layouts/CaseClose-Copy of Close Case Layout %28RFI%29.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Inquiry_Related_Investigation_Complete__c found (line 22, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 47.  layouts/CaseInteraction-Case Feed Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 70, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 48.  layouts/CaseInteraction-Case Order Feed Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 71, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 49.  layouts/CaseInteraction-Case Product Complaint Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 69, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 50.  layouts/CaseInteraction-Case RFI Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 68, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 51.  layouts/CaseInteraction-Case ROR Feed Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 69, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 52.  layouts/CaseInteraction-Case Service Request Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Case.Closure_Notification_Mode__c found (line 72, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 53.  layouts/CaseMilestone-Case Milestone Layout.layout -- Error: Parent entity failed to deploy
[sf:deploy] 54.  layouts/Contact-Licensed Non-Prescribers.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Contact.Gender__c found (line 28, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 55.  layouts/Contact-Non Licensed Patient Care.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Contact.Gender__c found (line 28, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 56.  layouts/Contact-Prescribers.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Contact.Therapeutic_Area__c found (line 32, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 57.  layouts/Contract-Contract Layout.layout -- Error: Layout must contain an item for required layout field: Pricebook2Id
[sf:deploy] 58.  layouts/ContractLineItem-Contract Line Item Layout.layout -- Error: Parent entity failed to deploy
[sf:deploy] 59.  layouts/Entitlement-Entitlement Layout.layout -- Error: Parent entity failed to deploy
[sf:deploy] 60.  layouts/FeedItem-Feed Item Layout.layout -- Error: Layout must have at least 1 section
[sf:deploy] 61.  layouts/Invoice__c-Invoice Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Invoice__c.Service_Contract__c found (line 37, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 62.  layouts/Opportunity-Opportunity %28Marketing%29 Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Opportunity.Bill_To_Account__c found (line 26, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 63.  layouts/Opportunity-Opportunity %28Sales%29 Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Opportunity.Bill_To_Account__c found (line 37, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 64.  layouts/Opportunity-Opportunity %28Support%29 Layout.layout -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named Opportunity.Bill_To_Account__c found (line 29, column 26)
[sf:deploy] Component Failures:
[sf:deploy] 74.  layouts/UserAlt-User Profile Layout.layout -- Error: Cannot use field:Name in a layout
[sf:deploy] 75.  applications/Force_com.app -- Error: defaultLandingTab must be included in tab list
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (2166/2200)  -- Processing Type: ApexTrigger
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Component Failures:
[sf:deploy] 76.  classes/ViewBOMPageForRMAEXTTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field Products_in_use__c for SObject Account (line 15, column 74)
[sf:deploy] 92.  classes/RMAdetailExtensionTest.cls -- Error: Invalid type: RMAdetailExtension (line 33, column 42)
[sf:deploy] 93.  classes/SalesOrderFromOpportunityExt.cls -- Error: No such column 'Bill_To_Account__c' on entity 'Opportunity'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 33, column 38)
[sf:deploy] 94.  classes/SalesOrderFromOpportunityExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid type: SalesOrderFromOpportunityExt (line 41, column 52)
[sf:deploy] 95.  classes/ServiceRequestChangeStatusExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field Products_in_use__c for SObject Account (line 16, column 74)
[sf:deploy] 96.  classes/SignedApprovalRequestHistoryExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field Products_in_use__c for SObject Account (line 32, column 74)
[sf:deploy] 97.  classes/AffiliationsController.cls -- Error: No such column 'Gender__c' on entity 'Contact'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 71, column 31)
[sf:deploy] 98.  classes/AffiliationsControllerTest.cls -- Error: Invalid type: AffiliationsController (line 27, column 41)
[sf:deploy] 99.  classes/Asset_Instance_ControllerExtensionTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field RecordTypeId for SObject Account (line 7, column 81)
[sf:deploy] 100.  classes/AuditTrailViewControllerTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field Caller_Name_Other__c for SObject Case (line 21, column 55)
[sf:deploy] 101.  classes/CallDetailNewEditPageExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field RecordTypeId for SObject Account (line 7, column 81)
[sf:deploy] 102.  classes/CallDetailViewPageExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field RecordTypeId for SObject Account (line 7, column 81)
[sf:deploy] 103.  classes/CallNewViewControllerTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field RecordTypeId for SObject Account (line 11, column 74)
[sf:deploy] 104.  classes/CallReportNewEditPageExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field Products_in_use__c for SObject Account (line 15, column 74)
[sf:deploy] 105.  classes/CallReportViewPageExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field Products_in_use__c for SObject Account (line 19, column 74)
[sf:deploy] 106.  classes/CallViewControllerExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field Products_in_use__c for SObject Account (line 17, column 74)
[sf:deploy] 107.  classes/CaseProductComplaintExt.cls -- Error: No such column 'RecordTypeId' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 42, column 22)
[sf:deploy] 108.  classes/CaseProductComplaintExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid type: CaseProductComplaintExt (line 28, column 50)
[sf:deploy] 109.  classes/CaseServiceRequestExt.cls -- Error: No such column 'RecordTypeId' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 24, column 26)
[sf:deploy] 110.  classes/CaseServiceRequestExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid type: CaseServiceRequestExt (line 45, column 44)
[sf:deploy] 111.  classes/CaseTriggerHandler.cls -- Error: No such column 'SuppliedName__c' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 140, column 49)
[sf:deploy] 112.  classes/CheckEntitlementEXT.cls -- Error: No such column 'Order__c' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 36, column 22)
[sf:deploy] 113.  classes/CheckEntitlementEXTTest.cls -- Error: Entity is not org-accessible (line 4, column 9)
[sf:deploy] 114.  classes/ContractLineItemNewEditPageExt.cls -- Error: Entity is not org-accessible (line 1, column 21)
[sf:deploy] 115.  classes/ContractLineItemNewEditPageExtTest.cls -- Error: Entity is not org-accessible (line 23, column 9)
[sf:deploy] 116.  classes/CreateAdvEventFromProdComplaintExt.cls -- Error: No such column 'Reporter_City__c' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 113, column 27)
[sf:deploy] 117.  classes/CreateAdvEventFromProdComplaintExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid type: CreateAdvEventFromProdComplaintExt (line 36, column 57)
[sf:deploy] 118.  classes/CreateRMAext.cls -- Error: No such column 'Return_Ship_to_Address__c' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 13, column 17)
[sf:deploy] 119.  classes/CreateRMAextTest.cls -- Error: Invalid type: CreateRMAext (line 34, column 35)
[sf:deploy] 120.  classes/CreateWorkOrderExt.cls -- Error: No such column 'Preferred_Time_End__c' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 32, column 25)
[sf:deploy] 121.  classes/CreateWorkOrderExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid type: CreateWorkOrderExt (line 42, column 40)
[sf:deploy] 122.  classes/CustomAccountLookupFromAccPlanTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field Products_in_use__c for SObject Account (line 20, column 74)
[sf:deploy] 123.  classes/CustomCompetitorLkupFrmAccPlanCtrlrTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field Products_in_use__c for SObject Account (line 18, column 74)
[sf:deploy] 124.  classes/ExpenseEditExtension.cls -- Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Asset__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 47, column 20)
[sf:deploy] 125.  classes/ExpenseEditExtensionTest.cls -- Error: Invalid type: ExpenseEditExtension (line 31, column 43)
[sf:deploy] 126.  classes/HierarchyController.cls -- Error: Didn't understand relationship 'RecordType' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 19, column 27)
[sf:deploy] 127.  classes/HierarchyControllerTest.cls -- Error: Invalid type: HierarchyController (line 34, column 38)
[sf:deploy] 128.  classes/AccountClassificationControllerTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field RecordTypeId for SObject Account (line 6, column 81)
[sf:deploy] 129.  classes/AccountControllerExtensionTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field RecordTypeId for SObject Account (line 14, column 93)
[sf:deploy] 130.  classes/AccountHierarchy.cls -- Error: Didn't understand relationship 'RecordType' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 34, column 27)
[sf:deploy] 131.  classes/AccountPlanController.cls -- Error: No such column 'Therapeutic_Area__c' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 85, column 43)
[sf:deploy] 132.  classes/AccountPlanControllerTest.cls -- Error: No such column 'Products_in_use__c' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 24, column 19)
[sf:deploy] 133.  classes/AccountPlanDetailExtTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field RecordTypeId for SObject Account (line 8, column 81)
[sf:deploy] 134.  classes/AccountPlanSharingControllerTest.cls -- Error: Invalid field RecordTypeId for SObject Account (line 8, column 81)
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (2166/2200)  -- Processing Type: ApexTrigger
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Component Failures:
[sf:deploy] 135.  triggers/CaseTrigger.trigger -- Error: Invalid type: CaseTriggerHandler (line 4, column 38)
[sf:deploy] 136.  triggers/ContractLineItemPriceBookOvverideTrigger.trigger -- Error: Entity is not org-accessible (line 5, column 53)
[sf:deploy] 137.  triggers/RMA_trigger.trigger -- Error: Variable does not exist: RMAAutoPopulateService (line 4, column 17)
[sf:deploy] 138.  triggers/ServiceContractCreateTrigger.trigger -- Error: Entity is not org-accessible (line 4, column 41)
[sf:deploy] 139.  triggers/WorkOrderTrigger.trigger -- Error: No such column 'Asset__c' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (line 30, column 31)
[sf:deploy] 140.  triggers/entitlementTriggerAudit.trigger -- Error: Entity is not org-accessible (line 1, column 36)
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Component Failures:
[sf:deploy] 141.  pages/OpportunityLineItemEdit.page -- Error: Apex class 'OpportunityLineItemEditExt' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 142.  pages/EntitlementEditAudit.page -- Error: Unknown object type Entitlement
[sf:deploy] 143.  pages/OpportunityView.page -- Error: Invalid field Product__c for SObject OpportunityLineItem
[sf:deploy] 144.  pages/OrderLineItemEdit.page -- Error: Apex class 'OrderDetailExtension' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 145.  pages/OrderLineItemEdit2.page -- Error: Apex class 'OrderDetailExtension' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 146.  pages/RMADetail.page -- Error: Apex class 'RMAdetailExtension' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 147.  pages/SalesOrderFromOpportunity.page -- Error: Apex class 'SalesOrderFromOpportunityExt' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 148.  pages/ServiceContractEditAudit.page -- Error: Unknown object type ServiceContract
[sf:deploy] 149.  pages/SolutionEditAudit.page -- Error: Invalid field Reason_for_Change__c for SObject Solution
[sf:deploy] 150.  pages/WorkOrderDetail.page -- Error: Apex class 'WorkOrderDetailExt' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 151.  pages/WorkOrderExpenseEdit.page -- Error: Apex class 'ExpenseEditExtension' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 152.  pages/accountAffiliations.page -- Error: Apex class 'AffiliationsController' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 153.  pages/accountHierarchy.page -- Error: Apex class 'HierarchyController' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 154.  pages/accountPlan.page -- Error: Apex class 'AccountPlanController' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 155.  pages/accountPlanWizardTemplate.page -- Error: Apex class 'AccountPlanController' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 156.  pages/accountSizing.page -- Error: Apex class 'AccountPlanController' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 157.  pages/accountView.page -- Error: Invalid field RecordType for SObject Account
[sf:deploy] 158.  pages/chatterFeedForRMA.page -- Error: Apex class 'RMAdetailExtension' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 159.  pages/plannedObjective.page -- Error: Apex class 'AccountPlanController' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 160.  pages/plannedStrategy.page -- Error: Apex class 'AccountPlanController' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 161.  pages/productContractTerm.page -- Error: Apex class 'AccountPlanController' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 162.  pages/salesSummary.page -- Error: Apex class 'AccountPlanController' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 163.  pages/CaseEditAuditTrail.page -- Error: Invalid field RecordType for SObject Case
[sf:deploy] 164.  pages/CaseProductComplaint.page -- Error: Apex class 'CaseProductComplaintExt' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 165.  pages/CaseServiceRequest.page -- Error: Apex class 'CaseServiceRequestExt' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 166.  pages/CheckEntitlement.page -- Error: Apex class 'CheckEntitlementEXT' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 167.  pages/contactAffiliations.page -- Error: Apex class 'AffiliationsController' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 168.  pages/ContractLineItemNewEditPage.page -- Error: Unknown object type ContractLineItem
[sf:deploy] 169.  pages/CreateAdvEventFromProdComplaint.page -- Error: Apex class 'CreateAdvEventFromProdComplaintExt' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 170.  pages/CreateWorkOrder.page -- Error: Apex class 'CreateWorkOrderExt' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 171.  pages/Create_RMA.page -- Error: Apex class 'CreateRMAext' does not exist
[sf:deploy] 172.  pages/OpportunityLineItemView.page -- Error: Could not resolve field 'Product__c' from <apex:outputField> value binding '{!OpportunityLineItem.Product__c}' in page OpportunityLineItemView
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to help you in technical area but little more with the approach. Basically, ant works on the same premises as change sets do - using meta data API and eventually the only difference is that you can do much more stuff in ANT.

If I go backwards your apex classes are not deployed because you are missing fields that are referenced by those classes, and you are missing fields because you cannot create them. There can be various reasons for that, either you are trying to change type of the field, or try to create a field that is valid in one type of ORG - source (you are migrating from partner org to standard org) to an ORG that cannot have such fields.

From my experience, when using ANT for all ORG deployment, it is doing steps in right order (objects, fields, and so on) so if you go to the log and start removing errors from the beginning you will find out, that after removing couple of first errors the others will be solved.

Svata

Comment: yeah exactly, but I tried retrieving in right order and trying to migrate in a right order but no luck

Comment: so, can you post the error messages you are getting? I will not be able to help you further without it.

Comment: Just to confirm, it seems you are migrating from service cloud (enitlements, service contract objects), is your target org service cloud as well (or has service objects enabled)?

Comment: just make sure that your target org is service cloud as well, and then it should eliminate first errors. if there are still more errors just post new error messages

Comment: can I enable service cloud option to my target developer environment(Which is free)?

Comment: Hello just create a new one from this link: https://www.salesforce.com/form/demo/crm-service-demos.jsp

Comment: I did creating account with the given link for free and no luck I am still facing the same issue

Comment: hm can you post your build.xml, package.xml (download and upload) and content of each folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [useful list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/commondeploymentissues.htm) detailing some of the more common issues with the force.com migration tool. One of the issues it mentions is:

> Retrieving custom fields on standard objects — When you use the wildcard symbol in package.xml, to retrieve all objects, you will not retrieve standard objects, or custom fields on standard objects.

Perhaps this or one of the other common issues might help you understand what's happening.